# Spring - YML array property is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-cloud

I am vainly trying to read an array of strings from the `application.yml`.
Both the `Environment` and the `@Value` annotation, always return null.

Everything works if I read an item, instead of the entire array.

Here the code:

## Sources

---

### Boot Application and Rest Controllers

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class WithEnvCtrl {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/with_env", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }, produces = "application/json")
    public String test() {

        System.err.println(env.getProperty("this.is.array[0]"));
        System.err.println(env.getProperty("this.is.array", List.class));
        System.err.println(env.getProperty("this.is.array", String[].class));

        return env.getProperty("this.is.array[0]");
    }
}

@RestController
class WithValueAnnotation {

    @Value("${this.is.array[0]}")
    private String first;

    @Value("${this.is.array}")
    private List<String> list;

    @Value("${this.is.array}")
    private String[] array;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/with_value_annotation", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST }, produces = "application/json")
    public String test() {

        System.err.println(first);
        System.err.println(list);
        System.err.println(array);

        return first;
    }
}
```

### application.yml file

```
this:
  is:
    array: 
      - "casa"
      - "pesenna"
```

## Results

---

The `WithEnvCtrl.test` method prints:

```
casa
null
null
null
```

The `WithValueAnnotation.test` method correctly sets the variable `first` with the first element of the array (`casa`). However, the annotations `@Value` on the attributes `list` and `array` cause the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'this.is.array' in string value "${this.is.array}"
```

Here is an example project: [property-array](https://github.com/paoloaq/property-array).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to use `@ConfigurationProperties` if you want to bind the whole list. Take a look at chapter "Loading YAML" in the docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml

Comment: Adding the annotation `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="this.is")` and defining an attribute `private List<String> array`, the result is always: `array` is null.

Comment: I think the docs mentioned that you also need a setter. Do you have that?

Comment: Solved by accessing the attribute through the `get` method, instead of `this.array`: the attribute is valorized only if I call the get method. Thanks a lot for the support!

Comment: @Alex Before posting the answer, I thought it appropriate fully test the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by:

- using the annotation `@ConfigurationProperties`;
- declaring an attribute with the same name as the yml property;
- defining the get method for the attribute;
- initializing the attribute or defining the set method.

---

Here the code:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="this.is")
class WithValueAnnotation {

    private List<String> array;

    public List<String> getArray(){
        return this.array;
    }

    public void setArray(List<String> array){
        this.array = array;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test_cfg", method = { RequestMethod.GET,
            RequestMethod.POST }, produces = "application/json")
    public String test() {

        System.err.println(array);

        return array.toString();
    }
}
```

Thanks @Quagaar.